# Compiler says that defined function is virtual

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, pure-virtual

When I try just to use the constructor for stackType, the compiler says that I cannot because the overloaded == is pure virtual. However, as you can see, I redefined it inside of stackType. Please help. (I think operators can be declared pure virtual, but I'm not sure. Im new to c++).

Thanks!

I cut the code down to minimum (school assignment):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

template <class Type>
class stackADT
{
public:
    virtual bool operator ==(const stackADT<Type> & b) = 0;
};
template <class Type>
class stackType: public stackADT<Type>
{
public:
    bool isFullStack() const;
    stackType(int stackSize = 100);
    bool operator == (const stackType<Type> & b) {
        if (this->stackTop != b.stackTop) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            bool equivalence = true;
            for (int cntr = 0; cntr < b.stackTop; cntr++) {
                if (this->list[cntr] != b.list[cntr]) {
                    equivalence = false;
                }
            }
            return equivalence;
        }
    }
private:
    int maxStackSize; //variable to store the maximum stack size
    int stackTop;     //variable to point to the top of the stack
    Type *list;       //pointer to the array that holds the
                      //stack elements
};
template <class Type>
bool stackType<Type>::isFullStack() const
{
    return(stackTop == maxStackSize);
} //end isFullStack

template <class Type>
template <class Type>
stackType<Type>::stackType(int stackSize) 
{
    if (stackSize <= 0)
    {
        cout << "Size of the array to hold the stack must "
             << "be positive." << endl;
        cout << "Creating an array of size 100." << endl;

        maxStackSize = 100;
    }
    else
        maxStackSize = stackSize;   //set the stack size to 
                                    //the value specified by
                                    //the parameter stackSize

    stackTop = 0;                   //set stackTop to 0
    list = new Type[maxStackSize];  //create the array to
                                    //hold the stack elements
}//end constructor



int main() {
    stackType<int> a(34);
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Don't implement `operator=` in a base class.  You are allowing child classes to compare to different types of child classes.  For example, given a `Shape` base class, you could compare a square with a circle.

Answer (score 3):

`operator==` in `stackADT` takes an argument of type `const stackADT<Type>&`, `operator==` in `stackType` takes one of type `const stackType<Type>&`. As they have a different signature, they are different functions.

If you want to make sure a function in a derived class overrides a function in the base class you can (in C++11) use the `override` keyword. It will make the compiler complain if your function does not override anything.

As it stands, your abstract base requieres that every derived class be comparable to the base. As such, you can base the comparison only on members that are available in the base. As comparison should be transitive, this also means that different derived classes can be compared based solely on members present in the base class. If this is not what you want, you should remove the operator from the base.

Comment: I tried changing it, however that would disqualify all the member variables I used inside. In addition, how would creating (what would be essentially) a new member function or definition for == render it invalid when I pass in the required parameters for that override?

Comment: @RaymondIacobacci I'm not sure what sure what you're asking, can you elaborate?

Comment: if I kept the definitions as they were (with the derived == having a parameter of stackType<Type>) than wouldn't that make the derived class non-abstract even though I'm not redefining my other ==?

Comment: In addition, changing the derived parameter to stackADT<Type> would make all the member variables inside of the parameter/object undefined.

Comment: @RaymondIacobacci See the edit to my answer. Forget the conversion. As it stands, yor are requiering that two derived classes of stackADT can be compared based on members of stackADT alone. If that is not what you want, you should delete it from the base class.

Comment: Okay. So I delete the virtual operator definition. However, what would happen if a dereferenced ptr of the base class that points to a derived class uses the operator?

Comment: @RaymondIacobacci Without an explicit cast, this won't work. Again, this is the point: If you don't know what kind of derived class your pointer points at, and the information present in the base class is not generelly sufficient to compare two derived classes, than you simply don't have enough information to make the comparison. If, on the other hand, you know to which derived class your pointer points, you can simply make a cast and call the `operator==` of the derived class.

Comment: Ok. Makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
bool operator == (const stackType<Type> & b)
```

does not override

```
virtual bool operator ==(const stackADT<Type> & b) = 0
```

because the parameters types are different.  The first takes a const reference to a `stackType<Type>`.  The second takes a const reference to a  `stackADT<Type>.`  So you have two different operator== functions in your derived class, the first being pure virtual -- hence the compiler error.

Several ways to fix this are referenced here:
[Dynamic Casts or Function Overloads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7452061/dynamic-casts-or-function-overloads) One method involves using a dynamic_cast and another uses *double dispatching*.

Comment: If you add the part about the override keyword from my answer (or something similar), I'll delete my answer. It's nice that you provide a solution.

Comment: I can't use cast for my assignment...is there anything else I can use to make it defined? Or should it not even be a virtual function in base class?

Comment: @RaymondIacobacci Honestly, the stackADT class does not provide any functionality at the moment.  You could just remove it.

Comment: I have to keep it because its part of my required source code. Believe me, if I didn't have to, I would delete it.

Comment: Sorry, figured out that doing this conversion is not such a great idea after all, so i brought my answer back...

Comment: @RaymondIacobacci can you use double dispatching? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch

Comment: I would but I cant for this assingment